# Different CMAKEs, unable to remove one of them

Tags: command-line, apt, python, cmake

I have two cmake commands, one has a path `/usr/local/bin/cmake`, which I would like to uninstall. I tried running `apt remove cmake` but it gives `Package 'cmake' is not installed, so not removed`. The other one (which I installed using pip) is located in a virtual environment. However, I would like to keep this one.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get install tree` and post output of `tree /usr/local` into question or upload it to pastebin (if long) and share link.

Comment: @N0rbert It is very long....Also, I am a bit uncomfortable revealing all packages I have installed....is there no other way to resolve this?

Comment: Output of `find /usr/local -iname '*cmake*'` maybe useful.

Comment: output of ```find /usr/local -iname '*cmake*' | cut -d '/' -f 1,2,3,4,5,6 | uniq | sed -e 's/\/usr\/local/ul/g'``` is as follows:

Comment: ul/bin/ccmake
ul/bin/cmake
ul/share/bash-completion/completions
ul/share/vim/vimfiles
ul/share/aclocal/cmake.m4
ul/share/emacs/site-lisp
ul/share/cmake-3.21
ul/share/cmake-3.21/Templates
ul/share/cmake-3.21/Modules
ul/share/cmake-3.21/Help
ul/share/cmake-3.23
ul/share/cmake-3.23/Templates
ul/share/cmake-3.23/Modules
ul/share/cmake-3.23/Help
ul/share/doc/Catch2
ul/lib/cmake
ul/lib/cmake/Catch2
ul/lib/cmake/opencv4
ul/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
ul/doc/cmake-3.21
ul/doc/cmake-3.23

Answer (score 0):

To remove locally installed `cmake` you have to remove its executable file by

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/cmake
```

Also it is recommended to inspect whole `/usr/local` directory tree for other locally installed objects.

Comment: But even then it's corresponding supporting directories/file will remain right?

Comment: Right, they will remain.

Comment: I want to remove those also. So, I want to remove all cmake files and install cmake again.